# Filter from multiples post method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a filter with angular that is like this.

```
 <div ng-show="filtroReduzido" class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Código Reduzido</label>
           <div class="form-group form-md-line-input no-hint right" style="padding-top: 3px;">
             <select id="reduzido" name="reduzido" chosen width="150" allow-single-deselect="true" ng-model="vm.filtro.numero_contrato" style="width:100%"
              ng-options="cliente.Numero_Contrato as cliente.Numero_Contrato for cliente in vm.importacaoSiltDet |unique:'Numero_Contrato'| orderBy:'Numero_Contrato'"></select>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that the "vm.importacaoSiltDet"comes from a post method, and i have two post methods, i need that the filters comes with all values for example:

In post method It return the IDs 1,2,3  and post method 2 return ID 4. In the filter i need to have 1,2,3,4.

I'm trying to create a empty array and insert with a forEach,but when it enters the array in debugger i geta error in console."Cannot set property 'Des_Servico' of undefined"

This is my code.If i can put this arrays result i can duplicate for the other method post.

```
vm.filtrarDet = function (Id_Fechamento) {
            id_fechamento = Id_Fechamento;
            $scope.$parent.vm.loading = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: _obterUrlAPI() + "AcompanhamentoSilt/FiltroSiltDet",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                params: {
                   Id_Fechamento:Id_Fechamento
                }

            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                vm.importacaoSiltDet = response.data;
                debugger;
                vm.importacaoFiltro[i].Des_Servico = vm.importacaoSiltDet[1].Des_Servico;
                vm.importacaoFiltr [i].Nome_Cliente = vm.importacaoSiltDet[1].Nome_Cliente;
                vm.importacaoFiltro[i].Numero_Contrato = vm.importacaoSiltDet[1].Numero_Contrato;
                i++;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                MessageBox("Erro", response.data.Message);
            });
        };
```

Comment: Where is `i` defined?

Comment: Sorry,forgot to post its defined inside the scope like this  var i = 0;